# Summing elements of a vector in R

Tags: r, vector

I'm trying to figure out how to add each respective component in a vector and store that in another vector. This is what I have so far:

```
# Create a function to roll a die n times. 
RollDie = function(n) sample(1:6, n, rep=T)
die1 = RollDie(500)
die2 = RollDie(500)
die3 = RollDie(500)
die4 = RollDie(500)
die5 = RollDie(500)
die6 = RollDie(500)
# Sum the values of the first component of each vector which represent the values
# of the six die rolled.
X = sum(die1[1], die2[1], die3[1], die4[1], die5[1], die6[1])
X
```

What I'm trying to do is sum the first, second, etc components of die 1 through 6.

So, the first component of X will be

```
sum(die1[1], die2[1], die3[1], die4[1], die5[1], die6[1])
```

the second component of X will be

```
sum(die1[2], die2[2], die3[2], die4[2], die5[2], die6[2])
```

the third component of X will be

```
sum(die1[3], die2[3], die3[3], die4[3], die5[3], die6[3])
```

and so on. X will have a length of 500.

I'm trying to find the appropriate command, but not having any luck. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use those 6 vector as columns and create a 500x6 dataset. Then simply create another column (at position 501) which sums the rows. Does that make sense, or you prefer to post an example as well? PS: Change the word DIE to DICE, because maybe people are afraid to reply. :-)

Comment: You want `X <- die1 + die2 + die3 + die4+ die5 +  die6`?

Comment: Very similar to @MrFlick 's solution but stored in a data.frame, in case you want to perform further analysis : `df = data.frame(die1, die2, die3, die4, die5, die6);
df$sum = df$die1+df$die2+df$die3+df$die4+df$die5+df$die6`, as I mentioned above. If you don't want to create a dataset you can use one of the other great solutions.

Comment: @AntoniosK thanks for the idea. that would work too. i didn't mean to scare anyone with die. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution with a vectorized approach:

```
rowSums(replicate(6, RollDie(500)))
```